# equality on inductive types

Tags: coq, induction

How do I prove the following trivial lemma:

```
Require Import Vector.

Lemma t0_nil: forall A (x:t A 0), x = nil A.
Proof.
Qed.
```

FAQ recommends `decide equality` and `discriminate` tactics but I could not find a way to apply either of them. For the reference, here is inductive definition:

```
Inductive t A : nat -> Type :=
  |nil : t A 0
  |cons : forall (h:A) (n:nat), t A n -> t A (S n).
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want to do is to invert on `x`. Unfortunately, it turns out that general inversion of dependently typed hypotheses is undecidable, see Adam Chlipala's CPDT. You can pattern match on the structure manually though, e.g. with:

```
Lemma t0_nil: forall A (x:t A 0), x = nil A.
  intros.
  refine (match x with 
  | nil => _
  | cons _ _ _ => _
  end).
  - reflexivity.
  - exact @id.
Qed.
```

In many cases you can also use [the tactic `dep_destruct` provided by CPDT](http://adam.chlipala.net/cpdt/repo/file/977b425331c3/src/CpdtTactics.v) . In that case your proof simply becomes:

```
Require Import CpdtTactics.

Lemma t0_nil: forall A (x:t A 0), x = nil A.
  intros.
  dep_destruct x.
  reflexivity.
Qed.
```

Comment: An elegant solution by Pierre Boutillier, taken from this [Coq-club post](http://coq-club.inria.narkive.com/wrDwvaNY/how-to-prove-that-all-vectors-of-0-length-are-equal-to-vector-nil#post2):
`Definition t0_nil A (x:t A 0) : x = nil A := match x with nil _ => eq_refl end.`